# BitBake add tmux package to image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to add the `tmux` package to the image that I build with BitBake.

The recipe for tmux is known to bitbake:

```
user@ubuntu:/opt/user/build$ bitbake-layers show-recipes | grep -A 1 tmux
tmux:
  meta-oe              2.1
```

Added this line to my conf/local.conf:

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " tmux"`

Clean & build the image:

```
bitbake -c cleansstate phytec-headless-image
bitbake -c clean phytec-headless-image
bitbake phytec-headless-image
```

Output of the build:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.36.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal-4.8"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-phytec-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "phyboard-mira-imx6-9"
DISTRO               = "yogurt"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "BSP-Yocto-i.MX6-PD18.1.2"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm armv7a vfp thumb neon callconvention-hard cortexa9"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            = "HEAD:5f660914cd7eec8117efccdf1eb29c466b4e74f7"
meta-oe              
meta-networking      
meta-python          
meta-multimedia      = "HEAD:eae996301d9c097bcbeb8046f08041dc82bb62f8"
meta-gstreamer1.0    = "HEAD:802a5db727edf0ec1d142122241c857bffab8667"
meta-phytec          = "HEAD:fcc5c4c755fd273b951ac4726b795ca5a9e9a5ed"
meta-rauc            = "HEAD:e9c3928d6c24bd58c613bd8334066021946d6347"
meta-qt5             = "HEAD:e6fb3850d43f857e87f7c53fc7df5933fef98cbd"
meta-yogurt          = "HEAD:608387f14f29509af5d029347ab2049764b453d2"
```

Copy the image to sdcard, it boots fine. But there is no tmux:

```
root@phyboard-mira-imx6-3:~# tmux
-sh: tmux: command not found
root@phyboard-mira-imx6-3:~# find / -name tmux
root@phyboard-mira-imx6-3:~#
```

Guidance or hints as to why tmux isn't added to the image are appreciated.

Comment: Try with `IMAGE_INSTALL_append +=`. But before flashing the image, you can check for the presence of `tmux` in `rootfs` build in `tmp/work/phyboard-mira-imx6-9/phytec-headless-image/*/rootfs. So that you can make sure it installed in target RFS before flashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the board I thought I was flashing was booting from NAND instead of the SD card that I was using. It has a small hardware-switch to chose where to boot from so I never actually booted the Image that I presumed included tmux.

As described by Parthiban you can verify that the binaries included with `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` are actually included, have a look at `image/*/rootfs`.

Answer (score -1):

Check if certain package is present on current Yocto Setup

**bitbake -s | grep**

see https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-94953